# Catching error code in Java from SQLPlus

Tags: java, sqlplus, error-code

I'm trying to execute a set of SQL scripts in a folder using Java and SQLPlus. My issue is that the return code I am getting from my SQL script is always 0, even if there are errors. This is what I am trying to do -

```
   StringBuffer command = new StringBuffer();
   String[] cmd = new String[3];
        cmd[0] = "cmd.exe";
        cmd[1] = "/C";
        cmd[2] = "echo WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 2 | sqlplus " + args[1] + "/" + args[2] + "@" + args[3] + "/" + args[4] + " " + fileName;
        for (int i = 0; i < cmd.length; i++) {
            command.append(cmd[i]);
            command.append(" ");
        }
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString());
   p.destroy();
   System.out.println("Exit value" + p.exitValue()); // Its always 0.
```

So ideally I am expecting error code 1, since i have used `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1`. But I am always getting exitValue as 0. Here's the script which violates the PK constraint -

```
INSERT INTO U_5837_F_6149_tbl VALUES ('E', 'B', 'Y');
INSERT INTO U_5837_F_6149_tbl VALUES ('E', 'M', 'Y');
INSERT INTO U_5837_F_6149_tbl VALUES ('E', 'M', 'Y');
```

EDIT - If I add, `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 2` to my scripts, it seems to work perfectly. Is it because my return value is being taken from cmd.exe rather than sqlplus. if yes, is there anyway i can bubble the error code from sql plus to cmd and take it from there?

Comment: You should better execute the queries by a jdbc driver instead.

Comment: The scripts can change regularly and then coming to Java everytime to change scripts doesn't seem like a good option. Also, since I am iterating over multiple files, we can have more files added. This is better in terms of scalability and this seems to be the only issue

Comment: The "0" you get is from "destroy( )". This is not the response of the db

Comment: I removed the p.destroy call and it still gives me 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ultimately I found a hack to this entire issue. Here's what I had to do -
1) I am still iterating over all the sql scripts in a directory, but instead of directly executing them, I call another script(test.sql) with the file location of the scripts I am iterating over as parameter. All that script does is call the desired script to be run. Here are the contents of my test.sql file -

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 999
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 99

prompt &1;
START &1;
```

&1 here represents the first parameter that's passed to this test.sql file, which represents the file that I am iterating over. START command runs that file and because of the WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT conditions, I get the right code back to Java.